# Powershell CSOM Mutli-Choice Checkbox

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I've reached the end of the internet on this. Many variations of this resource
[technet set_and_get_a_multi-choice_field](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Multi-Choice_Field)

Im running O365 Sharepoint and I have a multi-checkbox list or multi-select webpart.

When I query existing entries, the data comes back as an array. When I send an array to this field, it doesn't select the check boxes, though the values of the string is visible.

```
Multi-Value  {option1, option2, option3}
```

[image: multi-select]

I can't get this to work. Its really not even in the same format my code is in

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\ServOps\com\SharepointRuntimes\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\ServOps\com\SharepointRuntimes\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
$url = "https://my.foo.sharepoint"

Function Write-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
# <context>
#    <description>The list must be fetched before ListItemCreationInformation binds to put data</description>
# </context>
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)

$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()


# <context>
#    <description></description>
# </context>
$ListItemCreationInformation = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$NewListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemCreationInformation)
$NewListItem["Title"] = $TASK
$NewListItem["Approximate_x0020_delivery_x0020"] = $AVERAGE_DELIVERY_TIME_SLA 

$NewListItem.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Write-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle "My Sharepoint"
$context.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test script.

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

$url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/"
Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,$Password)
{
    write-host Get-SPOContext    
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password) #SecurePassword
    return $Context
}

Function Write-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
#$Context.ExecuteQuery()
# <context>
#    <description>The list must be fetched before ListItemCreationInformation binds to put data</description>
# </context>
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)

$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()


# <context>
#    <description></description>
# </context>
$ListItemCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$NewListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemCreationInformation)
$NewListItem["Title"] = "Title"
$ChoiceValue = "A","C"
$NewListItem["MyChoices"] = $ChoiceValue 

$NewListItem.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

$UserName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "pw" -AsPlainText -Force  
$spoContext = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

Write-ListItems -Context $spoContext -ListTitle "MyList"
$spoContext.Dispose()
Write-Host 'done'
```

Comment: I did try this as the first thing. Unfortunately this does not check the boxes it just adds a comma separated list. Thanks though.

Comment: The script works in my test environment, could you test by creating a test field with A B C to test.

Comment: It does work in the affect that data is added, but the checkboxes are not checked. When I click on the form element to expand in the GUI (its collapsed | hidden) the data I sent is wiped out, and the check boxes are not checked. I'm working with an O365 version